# Where are normal critter stats?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun

The Shapechange and (Critter) Form spells can transform a voluntary subject into a normal (non-paranormal) critter.  However, there are only stats for Dog, Great Cat, Horse, Shark, and Wolf on page 291 of the core book.  I've looked but not found any more official stats for normal critters.  Are all these, then, suppose to just rely on house rules?  Is there some source material out there covering normal critters that I've missed?  (Preferably in 4th Ed, but any edition would at least provide a base.)

Even Eagle Form, as one actual, provided example for (Critter) Form, is not possible without simply making up the stats for an eagle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SR4, the normal critters are in Running Wild.

Comment: Awesome!  Not sure how I missed it, but exactly what I was looking for.  For anyone else coming along here, looks like Amazon is not actually even near the cheapest place to get this. Check out the two stores [linked from here](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/products-page/core-supplements/running-wild/).